# Fail to open the ssh connection in a perl thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, ssh

I'm writing a script in perl which will be able to perform several action on a different hosts  in parallel. I'm using Net::OpenSSH for ssh session spawning since I need to have an ability of capturing the outputs from the commands. When I initialize the ssh connection from the main thread everythign is ok, but the following script returns the following error:

*Couldn't establish SSH connection: unable to establish master SSH connection: control command failed: child process 8392 does not exist: No child processes*

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

```
  our $threads{'1'} = {
    'thread' => '0',
    'ssh' => '0'
  };

  threadsInitialization();

  sub threadsInitialization{
        $threads{'1'}->{'thread'} = threads->create(sub {script();});
        $threads{'1'}->{'thread'}->join();
  }

  sub script{
        print("Test action will be executed now...\n");
        $threads{'1'}->{'ssh'}=sshInit(<host>,<user>,<passwd>); #<- error

        #execute some actions

  }

  sub sshInit{
        my ($host, $user, $passwd) = @_ or die "No arguments were supplied";
        print("Establishing ssh connection to $host as $user...\n");
        my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$host", user => "$user", passwd => "$passwd",         master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"], timeout => 600);
        $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
        print("ssh connection to $host as $user established successfully.");
        return $ssh;
  }
```

Comment: Its the 4th FAQ http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.60/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm#FAQ

Comment: Thank you! In the original script I had $SIG{CHLD}="IGNORE". That caused the problem probably. I have replaced it with local $SIG{CHLD}; and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: Please could you summarise your answer as an answer rather than a comment?